# Force invalidation of JavaFX properties

Tags: java, javafx, binding, properties, invalidation

I have a class with the getters/setters for interacting with an underlying device driver. The getter reads data from device and the setter writes data to device. I would add a FX property to this class in order to bind to a GUI controls. I build the property by using  JavaBeanPropertyBuilder and it's works. But the property value can be changed not only on GUI side but also on a device side, so I need update the properties by a timer and I want force invalidate the properties in order to update all bindings. Is it possible?

**UPD** with code example:

```
class MyDevice {
    public double getSpeed() {
        return (double)driver.getParameter("speed");
    }
    public void setSpeed(double value) {
        driver.setParameter("speed", value);
    }
    private DoubleProperty speed = new JavaBeanDoublePropertyBuilder().bean(this).name("speed").build();
    public DoubleProperty speedProperty() {
        return speed;
    }
}
```

Now, I bind `MyDevice::speedProperty` to GUI control and if a value has been changed on the driver side I want something like `speedProperty.invalidate()` to force handle all registered listeners and update the bindings. (I know about changes on the driver side by a timer's querying of a device status, for example, but not all available parameters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`fireValueChangedEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/adapter/JavaBeanDoubleProperty.html#fireValueChangedEvent--) method can be used to notify the `JavaBeanDoubleProperty` that the underlying data has been changed.

```
private JavaBeanDoubleProperty speed = new JavaBeanDoublePropertyBuilder().bean(this).name("speed").build();
```

```
speed.fireValueChangedEvent();
```

Comment: But this method is protected. How can I invalidate a property that is a member of my class?

Comment: @kerner1000 This method is not `protected`, but `public`, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/beans/property/adapter/JavaBeanDoubleProperty.html#fireValueChangedEvent--

Comment: Ah, its a JavaBeanProperty. Sorry,didnt see that.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is yes. However without you being more specific on your use case, there is just some general advice:

- You can add an [`InvalidationListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/InvalidationListener.html)` to your property, which is called whenever the bound property changes it's value
- You might consider to bind the property [`bidirectional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html#bindBidirectionaljavafx.beans.property.Property), so that changes from either direction are reflected at the other side.
- However bidirectional binding might not be preferable and in that case you can register a [`ChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html#addListener(javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener)) to the [`Property`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html).