# Can JavaFX properties be made to "fire"

Tags: java, javafx, properties

The classic Bill [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) illustrates how to use JavaFX properties in a not-GUI setting. As noted in the documentation, the notification only occurs when the value changes.  Thus, using the example, code such as this:

```
    electricBill.setAmountDue(100.00);
    electricBill.setAmountDue(100.00);
    electricBill.setAmountDue(100.00);
```

results in 1 and only 1 notification.  I like the idea of properties and I like the idea of bindings; however, the functionality that I need is to be able to control the notification so that even if the value doesn't change there is a notification to listeners.

Question:
1) Can this be achieved within the JavaFX properties architecture? If so, how?
2) If not, are there alternative property API's that permit this finer level of control?

This may be related to these [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589175/why-does-the-javabean-adapter-not-update-the-javafx-property) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185854/force-invalidation-of-javafx-properties).  It doesn't look like you can directly cause the firing of the event but you have to go through the java bean architecture as well.

Comment: As you've noted, a `ChangeListener` is only notified on actual changes, not on calls to `set`. There's no easy way to cause a change listener to be notified on all calls to `set`. Can you provide a use case? This seems to be trying to use this machinery for something for which it was not intended. Maybe there is an alternative approach to whatever it is you really want to do.

Comment: Play around with invalidation events, they may help you somehow.

Comment: Yes, I looked at this machinery to see if I can utilize the functionality to expand on the observables.  My use case is that each call to setX is dependent on when (in simulated time, not real time) that the set occurs.  Thus, setAmountDue(100.0) is actually different than setAmountDue(100.0) because (in my requirement) they may occur at different event times.

Comment: I am not referring to actual clock time. I have a simulated clock time that advances artificial time.  I was hoping to leverage the binding APIs because I have chains of observables that need notification.  But if each set call does not have a notification my requirement cannot be met.  I have started to look a reactive programming paradigms but they are overkill and seem to assume multi-threading (and my application is not multi-threaded).